# Ubuntu 22.04.2 loads to Command Line fails to Load GUI

Tags: command-line, gui, update-manager, gstreamer

After a recent set of upgrades Ubuntu will only load to command line. I have tried loading to older states by booting with `Shift` and selecting advanced start, without any luck.

I have tried to update and upgrade apt and reinstall the desktop...

When I try

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

I receive an error...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
gstreamer1.0-pipewire :
    Depends pipewire (=0.3.48-ubuntu1) but 0.3.48-ubuntu3 is to be installed
    Depends libpipewire-0.3-0 (=0.3.48-ubuntu1) but 0.3.48-ubuntu3 is to be installed
ubuntu-release-upgrade-gtk :
    Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (= 1:22.04.10) but 1:22.04.16 is to be installed
    Depends: python3-distupgrade (= 1:22.04.10) but 1:22.04.16 is to be installed
update-manager :
    Depends update-manager-core (= 1:22.04.9) but 1:22.04.10 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```